# How do I filter a list using the search bar in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

How do I filter a list using a search bar in SwiftUI.

This is what I have done so far, it shows all the information in the list but the list does not filter the information.

```
ForEach(
  (0..<self.appData.myJobs.count).filter(
    { "\($0)".contains(searchBar.text) || searchBar.text.isEmpty  }), 
  id: \.self) { index in
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you try to filter indices (like 1, 2, 3...), but I assume you try to filter by some texts, so it should be something like (I don't now your Job properties, so it is just assumption, but idea should be clear)

```
ForEach(
  (0..<self.appData.myJobs.count).filter({ i in // << here you get index 
      // assuming you have .jobTitle property in Job and want to filter by it
      // so just substitute your property
      self.appData.myJobs[i].jobTitle.contains(searchBar.text) || 
      searchBar.text.isEmpty }), 
  id: \.self) { index in
```