# Swift array binding filtering - Conformance of Binding<Value> to Sequence

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, binding

I'm using the swift package [`Defaults`][1] to manage a list of preferences in my app.
One of this property is an array of structures that I get using `@Default(.list) var list`.
In Swift UI, I loop on this list to edit the various elements.

```swift
@Default(.list) var list;

ForEach($list, id: \.wrappedValue.id) { element in 
...
}
```

It's working fine and it works as expected.

My problem is that I need to filter this list.
I'm using `$list.filter(...)` but I get a warning `Conformance of 'Binding<Value>' to 'Sequence' is only available in MacOS 12.0`.
Unfortunately, my app needs to run on MacOS 11.x.

I don't really understand what the warning means and how I can adapt my code to make it works with MacOS 11.x.

Thanks!

-- Update --

```swift
struct Stock: Codable, Identifiable, DefaultsSerializable {
   var id: String
   var currency: String = "USD"
}

extension Defaults.Keys {
    static let stocks = Key<[Stock]>("stocks", default: [])
}

struct StocksView: View {
    @Default(.stocks) var stocks

    func filterStocks(stock: Stock) -> Bool
    {
        return stock.currency == "USD"
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach($stocks.filter(filterStocks, id: \.wrappedValue.id) { stock in 
....
        }
    }
}


extension Binding where Value == [Stock] {//where String is your type
    func filter(_ condition: @escaping (Stock) -> Bool) -> Binding<Value> {//where String is your type
        return Binding {
            return wrappedValue.filter({condition($0)})
        } set: { newValue in
            wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
}







  [1]: https://github.com/sindresorhus/Defaults
```

Comment: Instead of using ForEach with Binding, use data directly to apply filter (like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64300838/12299030) and make binding in row view if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$list.filter` your are not filtering `list` you're filtering `Binding<[List]>` which doesn't conform to the protocol Sequence.

Add this extension to your project and see if it works

```
extension Binding where Value == [String] {//where String is your type
    func filterB(_ condition: @escaping (String) -> Bool) -> Binding<Value> {//where String is your type
        return Binding {
            return wrappedValue.filter({condition($0)})
        } set: { newValue in
            wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: `Binding` in a `ForEach` requires `SwiftUI 3+`

However, you can pass the normal array and whenever you need a `Binding` use this function:

```
extension Stock {
    func binding(_ array: Binding<[Stock]>) -> Binding<Stock> {
        Binding {
            self
        } set: { newValue in
            guard let index = array.wrappedValue.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == newValue.id}) else {return}
            array.wrappedValue[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

So your code would look like this:

```
ForEach(stocks.filter(filterStocks), id: \.id) { stock in
        ....
    SomeViewRequiringBinding(value: stock.binding(stocks))
}
```

Comment: Using this method, I get a new warning: `Conformance of 'Binding<Value>' to 'RandomAccessCollection' is only available in macOS 12.0 or newer`.

Comment: Oh! Forgot about that, using Binding in forEach is only available in SwiftUI 3. Hence the warning.

Comment: I edited my answer with more details on implementation using your technic

Comment: Thanks. Your solution seems to work great and I don't have warning anymore. It also simplify a lot of things in my codebase.